# Regex for word groups with slash (Notepad++)

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want the regex to be able to change strings like these:

```
chase away/out
deceased/departed family member
increase/multiply greatly
stupid/innocent-looking
small storeroom/shed/depot/cellar
make somebody extremely mad/angry
blur/cloud over/mist up completely
an/my honour
```

To these

```
chase away|chase out
deceased family member|departed family member
increase greatly|multiply greatly
stupid-looking|innocent-looking
small storeroom|small shed|small depot|small cellar
make somebody extremely mad|make somebody extremely angry
blur completely|cloud over completely|mist up completely
an honour|my honour
```

Before these strings there could be these characters:

```
 ,[that is SPACE and comma]
|
[TAB]
```

After these strings there could be these characters:

```
, [that is comma and SPACE]
|
[newline]
```

Comment: I think the honorable delegate is saying that you've shown no code attempts at all.  
Furthermore, I don't understand the comma/space/tab/newline stuff. Your input should contain all relevant possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Take this line:

```
blur/cloud over/mist up completely
```

It would be very hard for a regular expression to determine that you expect

```
blur completely|cloud over completely|mist up completely
```

and not

```
blur up completely|cloud over up completely|mist up completely
```

In other words, that `up` sticks to `mist` and not to `completely`.

To accomplish this task, you would need some kind of artificial intelligence/natural language processing capabilities (can you expand this sentence mechanically?) Regular expressions are somewhat underpowered to include such things.

Comment: Thanks, I see what you mean. What if this example was not taken into consideration.

Comment: @greektranslator Then you would be able to do something with it. Maybe not in one regular expression but in several runs. I won't do it because regular expressions are menial and boring, and more often than not there are better tools for the job.